# Adjust menu items to float right at same height as logo and toggle menu to expand normally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a menu-bar with on the left side my ***brandlogo*** and floating right I have my menu items (car, house, street, boat). I want these menu items to be at the same horizontal height as my *** brandlogo *** , now they somehow fall below that, not on same line clearly.
Second issue is that my mobile toggle menu works, but when you expand the menu then first its floated right and then it takes the full width. So it opens on the right (probably because of float:right) and then moves to the left to take the full 100% width I specified. I would like the toggle mobile menu to just open on the full width and not float right first.
Is it possible to achieve my goals.
Here my BOOTPLY... [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/zHG4nPE2kV#)
(just click on the mobile phone icon to see my second part of my problem).

```html
<header id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
                       
                        <div class="clearfix container navbar-fixed-top">
                            <div class="clearfix menu-container">
                                <div class="pull-right clearfix toggle_btn_wrap">
                                    <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left brand-name">
                                    <a href="#"><img alt="***brandlogo***" src="assets/images/logo.png"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>
                                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                   <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                                  <li>
                                    <a href="/car" title="car">car</a>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                    <a href="/house" title="house">house</a>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                    <a href="/street" title="street">street</a>
                                     </li>
                                     <li>
                                    <a href="/boat" title="boat">boat</a>
                                     </li>
  </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></div></div>

</div>


            <div id="push"></div>
        </header>
```

Comment: To get the logo and the menu to be side by side, remove `<div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>`

Comment: @ntgCleaner - if I remove that code then toggle mobile menu shows strange behaviour when expanding menu, so I have to keep it. Any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: Ok, you could `display:none` when in desktop mode in your CSS

Comment: I don't have an answer for your second question though, sorry